# Eclipse PMD automatic reparse once source file is updated?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I am using PMD plugin under Eclipse.

**How can one force PMD plugin to reparse a source file once it is updated to eliminate fixed warnings?**

After right click on a project name in Package Explorer, I select `PMD -> Check Code with PMD` and many warnings/errors are shown. Then I start modification of source code to fix the issues, but warning don't disappear automatically.

Every time to verify I need to `PMD -> Check Code with PMD` manually which is very tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 4.0 release of the Eclipse Plugin you have to go to the main preference page an ensure that the "Check code after saving" option is turned on.

Comment: Thanks! I appeared that version 3.2.6 was installed. After reinstallation that option did appear.